# is this primes generator pythonic

Tags: generator, python, primes

Is the following code for generating primes pythonic?

```
def get_primes(n):
    primes=[False,False]+[True]*(n-1)
    next_p=(i for i,j in enumerate(primes) if j)
    while True:
        p=next(next_p)
        yield p
        primes[p*p::p]=[False]*((n-p*p)//p+1)
```

Note that next(next_p) will eventually throw a StopIteration error which somehow ends the function get_primes. Is that bad?

Also note that next_p is a generator which iterates over primes, however primes changes during iteration. Is that bad style?

adding the following if statement gets it under 0.25 seconds for the first million primes:

```
if p*p<=n:
    primes[p*p::p]=[False]*((n-p*p)//p+1)
```

Comment: you can save one line if you want using `primes=[False,False]+[True]*(n-1)`, also adding complexity you can optimize to use half a sieve, skip even numbers. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/464543

Comment: test your code for 0,1,2,3 without the line `if p*p<=n:`... in my machine that line is not needed

Comment: Thanks, I forgot [False]*(non positive) = []

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python) for many examples in python for fast prime generation

Comment: Thanks Kimvais, I tested mine against the code there and mine is about 30x slower, but I wanted the emphasis on "pythonic" instead of speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not bad that `next(next_p)` throws a `StopIteration` error -- that's what a generator always does when it runs out of items!

Changing the length of a list while iterating over it is a bad idea. But there's nothing wrong with simply changing the contents. Overall, I think this is a rather elegant, if basic, seive.

One small observation: when you "cross out" the multiples of prime numbers, you'll find, if you think about it for a bit, that you don't have to start with `p * 2`. You can skip ahead to `p ** 2`.

Comment: Ah of course skip to p**2 as all smaller primes are already found. I will change it thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the `StopIteration`, indeed that is the expected behaviour for generators.

I would say this implementation is more pythonic (not necessarily more efficient):

```
def get_primes(n):
  """Generates prime numbers < n"""
  return (x for x in xrange(2,n) if all(x % i for i in xrange(2,x)))
```

*Pythonic* to me means clear, concise, readable, and using the strengths of the language.   While I can see your implementation is some sort of sieve, I only know that from prior experience with those kind of algorithms.  The implementation above I can read directly as a straight-forward test of divisibility.

---

***Note:*** there is a minor difference in the interface, your implementation would yield primes <= n whereas my implementation would yield primes < n.  Obviously this can be changed easily and trivially (just change n to n+1 in the function body), but I feel it is more pythonic to generate primes up-to-but-not including n to be more consistent with the way, say, `range()` builtin works.

---

***EDIT: JUST FOR FUN***

Here is a *least* pythonic implementation, and probably pretty inefficient too :)

```
def get_primes(n):
  import re
  return (x for x in xrange(2,n) if re.match(r'^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$', '1' * x) is None)
```

I call this the least pythonic because you would be scratching your head for some days to figure out how it works if you haven't seen this trick before!!

Comment: Thanks mate. Yeah this will get really slow once n gets much bigger than 1000, but is easy to read.

Comment: Note: I am only trying to answer about _pythonic_, if you are interested in the _fastest_ way in python, this question has been well covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python).

Comment: yup, I would write something like this if i quickly needed some small primes, or if i had 0 memory. I have used your idea to submit another answer which is not quite as pythonic but slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another somewhat pythonic solution motivated by @wim, however you can see it is slightly slower than the first method.

```
def get_primes2(n):
    primes=[]
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        small_primes=(p for p in primes if p*p<=i)
        if all(i%p for p in small_primes):
            yield i
            primes.append(i)

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("list(get_primes(10**5))",number=5,setup="from __main__ import get_primes")/5.0)
"0.0350940692182945"
print(timeit.timeit("list(get_primes2(10**5))",number=5,setup="from __main__ import get_primes2")/5.0)
"8.226938898658908"
```

Comment: which imp is `get_primes` referring to here?

Comment: the one in my question. If you add if p*p<=n, you get 0.025. wim, I didn't try your one, i assumed it would be very slow :)

Comment: BTW instead of strings you can pass function objects to `timeit`, it's quicker to write because you can omit "setup". Apply arguments using `fnuctools.partial` or a lambda expression.